# CGAL:: Surface Reconstruction -- reconstructed point cloud can't be rendered/visualize in any 3D viewers

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, point-clouds, cgal

I used CGAL to preprocess my pointcloud(.ply) file.

Results after each preprocess can be rendered/visualize.

But after applying **advance front surface reconstruction** to the point cloud. I can't render it anymore.

I followed this [code](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/tuto_reconstruction.html#TutorialsReconstruction_recap) but I only used the advance front as a reconstruction method.

Comment: You mean you cannot open the off file generated nor in the CGAL demo nor in meshlab?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.